# Bazaar with .sln and .csproj files

Tags: .net, bazaar

First, let me try to describe how I've got my Bazaar project organized, it's something like this:

- Library Project

  - Trunk
  - Developer one
  - Developer two
- Application Project 1

  - Trunk
  - Developer one
  - Developer two
- Application Project 2

  - Trunk
  - Developer one
  - Developer two

Where both application project 1 and application project 2 reference the library project.

The problem I'm running into is that the reference path to the library for the code in developer one's project, developer two's project, and in the trunk are all different, as they should be. developer one should reference his copy of the library, developer two should reference his, and the trunk should reference the trunk library.

Is there a better way for me to organize these projects or is there some tricky way to put my .sln and .csproj files into revision control with fancy paths?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use relative paths.  Visual Studio is capable of using `..\..\MyProj.csproj` -style path referencing.  If all your libraries are in the same repository, this should be no problem.  You can even edit the sln and csproj files with a text editor.  Just unload them from visual studio first.

Comment: yeah, that's looking good, a quick google search of ".sln relative path" brought up a bunch of source control posts.  The problem is, I can't think of a relative path that will work with the folder structure I have.

Comment: So, I restructured my folders so they're all in one repository instead of each in their own repository.